# How to generate a new random number from an ActionListener switch case?

Tags: java, swing

I'm making a Higher Lower minigame and one of the requirements is a restart button. I'm done clearing the scores and past user inputs when the restart button is clicked but I can't seem to make the program generate a new random integer.

Here's the code for the main class

```
package HigherLower;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main extends JFrame{
    //Variables
    static Random ran = new Random();
    static int x = ran.nextInt(100) + 1;
    
    static int answer = x;
    static int guessCounter = 0;
    
    //Menus
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu optionsMenu = new JMenu("Options");
    JMenuItem restartGame = new JMenuItem("Restart");
    JMenuItem exitGame = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    JMenu helpMenu = new JMenu("Help");
    JMenuItem howToPlay = new JMenuItem("How To Play");
    
    //Action
    HigherLowerGame Ggame;
    
    //Main sections
    static JPanel guessCount = new JPanel();
    static JPanel numberPrint = new JPanel();
    static JPanel controls = new JPanel();
    
    //Score Label
    static JLabel guessLabel = new JLabel("Guesses: ");
    static JLabel guessValue = new JLabel(String.valueOf(guessCounter));
    static JLabel playerAnswer = new JLabel("");
    static JLabel guessNumber = new JLabel("Type your guess: ");
    
    //TextField
    static JTextField playerGuess = new JTextField();
    
    
    public Main(String name){
        super(name);
        this.Ggame = new HigherLowerGame();
        setResizable(false);
        
        initHeadDisplay();
        initMidDisplay();
        initBotDisplay();
        
        //Options Menu
        restartGame.setActionCommand("restart");
        restartGame.addActionListener(Ggame);
        
        exitGame.setActionCommand("exit");
        exitGame.addActionListener(Ggame);
        
        //Help Menu
        howToPlay.setActionCommand("help");
        howToPlay.addActionListener(Ggame);
    }
    
    private void initHeadDisplay(){
        guessCount.add(guessLabel);
        guessLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        guessCount.add(guessValue);
        guessValue.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
    }
    
    
    private void initMidDisplay(){
        numberPrint.add(playerAnswer);
        playerAnswer.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    }
    
    private void initBotDisplay(){
        controls.add(guessNumber);
        controls.add(playerGuess);
        playerGuess.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 30));
        
        playerGuess.addKeyListener(Ggame);
    }
    
    public void addComponentsToPane(final Container pane) {
        pane.add(guessCount, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        guessCount.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 50));
        pane.add(numberPrint, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pane.add(controls, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        controls.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 50));
    }
    
    private static void createAndShowGUI(){
        Main frame = new Main("Higher Lower Game");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 200));
        
        frame.initMenu();
        frame.setJMenuBar(frame.menuBar);
        frame.addComponentsToPane(frame.getContentPane());

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private void initMenu(){
        menuBar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 20));
        
        optionsMenu.add(restartGame);
        optionsMenu.add(exitGame);
        menuBar.add(optionsMenu);
        
        helpMenu.add(howToPlay);
        menuBar.add(helpMenu);
    }
   
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
    
}
}
```

And here's the ActionListener class:

```
package HigherLower;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.Random;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class HigherLowerGame implements ActionListener, KeyListener {
    
    Main obj = null;
    Random ran = new Random();
    int randomNumber = ran.nextInt(100) + 1;   

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        switch(ae.getActionCommand()){
            case "restart": Main.guessCounter = 0;
            Main.guessValue.setText(String.valueOf(Main.guessCounter));
            Main.playerAnswer.setText("");
            break;
            

            case "exit": System.exit(0);
            break;
            
            case "help": JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Higher Lower is a game about guessing a number from 1-100. If the player's guess is higher than the generated number,"
                    + " the player's guess will light up green but if its lower, its gonna light up red.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke) {
        char c = ke.getKeyChar();
        
        if(!Character.isDigit(c) || (c == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE || (c == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE))){
            ke.consume();
        }
        
        if(c == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
            int jml = Integer.parseInt(Main.playerGuess.getText());
            if(jml > Main.answer){
                Main.playerAnswer.setText(String.valueOf(jml));
                Main.playerAnswer.setForeground(java.awt.Color.green);
                Main.guessCounter++;
               
            }
            
            else if(jml< Main.answer){
                Main.playerAnswer.setText(String.valueOf(jml));
                Main.playerAnswer.setForeground(java.awt.Color.red);
                Main.guessCounter++;
            }
            
            else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nailed it! It took you " + Main.guessCounter + " guesses! The number was " + Main.answer );
            }
            Main.guessValue.setText(String.valueOf(Main.guessCounter));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {
    }

    
    
}
```

Comment: Don't you just need to add the following line to `case "restart"` block of `switch` statement in `actionPerformed` method of class `HigherLowerGame`: `Main.answer = Main.ran.nextInt(100) + 1;`

Comment: Oops, that must've flew across my mind, tried it and it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instance fields are initiated only once on creating the instance.

Because you assign random value to the field `randomNumber` only on initialization, and you create `HigherLowerGame` instance only once, the random number is assignment only once per application lifecycle.